# Calling overloaded constructor not possible: only one is recognized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, constructor, overloading

I have multiple constructors like this, coming from a different class:

```
public Manager(param p1){ ... }
public Manager(param p1, param p2){ ... }
public Manager(param p1, param p2, ... ){ ... }
...
```

All constructors have a `public Manager` with different parameters. Changing the constructors is impossible to me, by the way, as that code comes from somewhere else.

Anyway, I am only able to call one specific constructor. If I try to add other parameters that constructor is not recognized and I get errors like

> converting from param pX to param pY not possible

The class containing the constructors etc. is included with the corresponding using-directive (as I said, I CAN call that one constructor without problems)

I´m clueless what might be the reason for this. Please help.

Comment: It will be easier to find the problem if you can show to real signatures of the constructors and how you try to call them. I.e. what type is `pX` and what are you passing as `pX`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to pass arguments with incorrect types. In order to be sure that the correct overload will be used you can specify the named arguments.

Example:

```
 var manager = new Manager(item: "value", item1: "value", item2: 1);
```